# Positioning Highstock Zoom Buttons outside the chart area within a <div>

Tags: javascript, button, position, zooming, highcharts

I have read the configuration options on Highstock charts but couldn't find anything concerning the position of the Zoom Buttons outside the chart area or using own buttons for this purpose.

I guess I have to use the `.rangeSelector.buttons` in the `chart` object, but I can't figure it out. If somebody has tried something similar I would be very glad if you could share your approach with me.

The best would be if I could use the zoom functions with these own Bootstrap buttons:

```
<div style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;"> 
   <button href="#" type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-outline btn-primary active">12h</button>
   <button href="#" type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-outline btn-primary">2d</button>
   <button href="#" type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-outline btn-primary">1w</button>
   <button href="#" type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-outline btn-primary">1m</button>
   <button href="#" type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-outline btn-primary">All</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add events to buttons which will set extremes (see [Axis.setExtremes](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Axis.setExtremes)) in the navigator x axis (optionally, you can set data grouping [Axis.setDataGrouping()](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/Axis.setDataGrouping).

```
$('#all').on('click', function() {
  var chart = Highcharts.charts[0];
  chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(chart.xAxis[1].min, chart.xAxis[1].max);
});

$('#20d').on('click', function() {
  var chart = Highcharts.charts[0],
    max = chart.xAxis[0].max,
    interval = 3600 * 1000 * 24 * 20;

  chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(max - interval, max);
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/gyrv1qxp/1/